# Create list of all rows where value is not appearing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (foo) like this:

```
fk | value
========
A  |  1
A  |  2
B  |  1
C  |  1
```

I try to create a list of all fk's where a specific value is not appearing, e.g. the value `2`.

One attempt would be to do it like this:

```
SELECT fk 
FROM foo
WHERE value <> 2;
```

But this would still return `A, B, C`, because `A` has two entries and one of them is not `2`. I need `B, C` instead.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. They are all working :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not noticed the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or by using GROUP BY in combination with HAVING NOT and a conditional SUM

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 foo.fk
FROM
 foo
GROUP BY
 foo.fk
HAVING 
 NOT SUM(foo.value = 2)
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kyP2ykqDEHTkM1E6NsdkEn/0

Comment: *Note to myself*: Make sure that there is no space between `SUM` and `(`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `not exists` :

```
select f.*
from foo f
where not exists (select 1 from foo f1 where f1.fk = f.fk and f1.value = 2);
```

Comment: Is this selfjoin?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn. . . No, this is a `subquery` with `correlation` approach. No any `JOIN` involved.

Comment: For each `fk` in `foo f`, you have to match against `foo f1.fk`, I suppose? And it has a short circuit to end the match if any `f1.value = 2` found. It's still like a join, I suppose

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn: yes, this is equivalent to an anti-join pattern. If we wrote this as a join, the EXPLAIN output would show "Not exists" in the Extra column. Equivalent would be: `SELECT f.fk FROM foo f LEFT JOIN foo k ON k.fk = f.fk AND k.value = 2 WHERE k.fk IS NULL`  (and add `GROUP BY f.fk` to get a distinct list of fk).  But for this result, I'd prefer the approach from Raymond... the conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your `fk` mapped with your value then eliminate it:

```
SELECT f.fk
FROM foo f
WHERE f.fk NOT IN (SELECT f1.fk FROM foo f1 WHERE f1.value = 2)
```

Comment: Just be sure that `f1.fk` doesn't return a NULL value, ... if we have a guarantee that `fk` column in `foo` is non-NULL, that is sufficient. In the more generat case, we could include `AND f1.fk IS NOT NULL` in the subquery to give us that guarantee. (If even one NULL value is returned by the subquery, then the `NOT IN` will *not* evaluate to true.)